# Desktop.print() won't automatically print in Windows Photo Viewer

Tags: java

I wrote an app that automtically prints documents, using the `Desktop.print()` method. For MS Word, MS Excel, Notepad, and Adobe Reader it flashed the app for a second, then prints, which is exactly what I want. When I try and print an image file (.jpeg, .png, etc..) it opens Windows Photo Viewer, which is my default app for images, but it doesn't print them. Instead it takes me to the print screen and I have to manually click on print. Any idea why there would be a difference in behaviour like this?

```
DefaultListModel<File> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
Boolean openDocsAfterPrint = false;

void openAndPrintDocs() {
    int fileIndex = 0;

    while (fileIndex < listModel.size()) {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            if (openDocsAfterPrint == true) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(listModel.get(fileIndex));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().print(listModel.get(fileIndex));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        fileIndex++;
    }
}
```

Again, it's working fine for everything except for Photo Viewer. Thanks.

Comment: it could be great if you post some code here , so we can help you or at least know from where the problem is coming

Comment: Added the relevant code above...

Comment: That's an issue with Windows Photo Viewer and not Java, there probably nothing you can do, next to writing your own jni/jna solution which probably won't solve the problem

Comment: Yeah I knew it was on the Windows end, I was just hoping that maybe there was another solution or workaround for it. It's just weird because all of the other Microsoft apps work the way I want them to, you would think that they would have the same functionality, but I guess not. Thanks though.